# AngularJS Dynamically Loading Plain Old Javascript Through Source Tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-api, angular-promise

I am trying to load some javascript dynamically using AngularJS promises.

HTML file (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="main">

<ng-view></ng-view>

</body>
</html>
```

AngularJS file (main.js)

```
angular.module('main', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/',
            {
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'partial.html',
                resolve: {
                    temp: MainCtrl.testFn
                }
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })
    })

MainCtrl = angular.module('main')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function () {

    });

angular.module('main')
    .factory('MyFactory', function($q) {
        data = {
            loadJS: function() {
                var deferred = $q.defer()
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript'
                script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js'
                script.onload = function() {
                    deferred.resolve('Google Client Library loaded')
                }
                document.body.appendChild(script)
                return deferred.promise
            }
        }
        return data
    })

MainCtrl.testFn = function($log, MyFactory) {
    return MyFactory.loadJS().then(function(result) {
        $log.debug(result)
        gapi.client.load()
    })
}
```

The onload method is called (as the promise is resolved and debug line printed), but an error is being thrown because the client property is not found on gapi (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined).

What am I missing? Does anyone have a better way of dynamically loading JS with Angular promises (using only Angular and JS)?

Comment: Why aren't you using a proper loader like requireJS, or just including the script tag with a link in the page? While this is possible, you better have a good reason

Comment: I want to avoid race conditions between the javascript being loaded and being used. In my real app, I have a bunch of chained Angular promises that must be resolved before routing occurs.  I haven't looked into requireJS b/c I was hoping to find a good Angular only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the script is loading successfully but gapi.client is not available immediately. You need to provide handler to google api url on that purpose (some global function).

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function(googleClientLoader) {
  googleClientLoader.load().then(
    function() {
      console.debug(gapi.client);
    }
  )
})

.factory('googleClientLoader', function($q) {
  return {
    load: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer()
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript'
      script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad';
      window.handleClientLoad = function() {
        deferred.resolve('Google Client Library loaded');
      }
      document.body.appendChild(script)
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load the content and use eval(data) to evaluate the Javascript.
a  tag won't be processed as it is generated after the page loads.

Comment: Encouraging people to use 'eval' is never a good thing. It's a big vulnerability.